# Nginx proxy can not find static script information in odoo docker environment

Tags: nginx

On a server I have a docker container running odoo (from the official image). I want to access it on url http://myserver.com/odoo with https proxiying. I have an nginx docker container which is supposed to do that.

Odoo container has been launched with

```
docker run --name odootest --link dbodoo:db -t odoo
```

Nginx container has been launched with the `--link odootest:odoo`.

Here is my nginx configuration file

```
upstream odoo {
            server odoo:8069;

}

# this one for the http to https rewrite
server {

        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

        rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/initial.log;
        error_log    /var/log/nginx/initialerror.log;
        rewrite_log on;

}

#this one for the proper nginx job
server {
        listen 443 ;

 <... ssl certificates part >

        location  ^~ /odoo/ {

                  proxy_pass http://odoo/;

                  # force timeouts if the backend dies
                  proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503;

                  # set headers
                  proxy_set_header Host $host/odoo/;
                  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                  proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


                  # Let the OpenERP web service know that we're using HTTPS, otherwise
                  # it will generate URL using http:// and not https://
                  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

                  proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /odoo/;
                  proxy_redirect http://myserver.com/ https://myserver.com/odoo/;
                  }

}
```

Everything works ok for the request itself but images, jquery and js scripts are not correctly found, as the html code returned by the odoo container looks like

```
   <script src="/web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the navigator is looking for `myserver.com/web/static/...` locations instead of `myserver.com/odoo/web/static...`

I thought this could be managed by all the proxy_header statements in my location part but seems not. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using absolute url's in your code, you should be using relative ones, for example this:

```
<script src="/web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be changed to this:

```
<script src="web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

That way the site when accessed over `https://myserver.com/odoo/` the images/js/css will be requested at a relative url to that `https://myserver.com/odoo/web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js`

Comment: This looks good to me but those absolute urls are sent directly by the odoos server. Is there any simple (ie configuration not code changing) to change that in odoo's server?